# AS3 air android Change to landscape keyboard

Tags: android, actionscript-3, keyboard, landscape, air-android

Can anyone tell me how i can set the keyboard to landscape in as3? I'm using flash cs5 and air for android and i don't have the auto aspect ration turned on, so what i want is to set the key board to come up in landscape in code.

Thanks in advance!!!

FlashCreated

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard will appear in the orientation you set from either the properties panel or through code.